# How to use clsx in nested components in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, clsx

I'm using clsx in a React application and I have an issue on how to use it when there are mappings and nested components.

For example:

```
return ( 
  <div>
    <button onClick={doSomething}>{isOpened ? <Component1 /> : <Component2 />}</button>
    <div className={clsx(containerClasses)}>
        {myData.map((item, index) =>
          <OuterComponent as='div' key={item.name}>
            {({ open }) =>
              <>
                <InnerComponent
                  className={}// how to compute this value?
                >
```

Above we have a returned JSX, an outer div element, a value `isOpened` which comes from the state so we have access to it everywhere. This means we can implement the following `containerClasses`:

```
const containerClasses = {
    'class1 ': true,
    'class2': isOpened,
    'class3': !isOpened
  };
```

All good until here.

But as you can see, there is `myData.map(...)` which iterates through an array. Here, I would need to compute `innerClasses` based on the value of `open`. But this value is accessible just inside the loop, not outside the return and inside the function.

Is there a way to solve this problem with clsx?

Comment: create a method called getClasses passing open as a prop to it and return classes object

Comment: @Madhuri could you develop that into an answer, please?

Comment: I have tried to add pseudo code, see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const getClasses= (open) => {
  return clsx({
     [classes.class1]: open, // desired classname and condition
  })
}
```

```
<InnerComponent
    className={getClasses(open)} //call a method here
>
```